# Getting invalid result when using Noda Time c#

Tags: c#, nodatime

Assume Instant variable contains "4/8/2014 11:09:24 AM" when i pass this value to this method it gives me an output "4/8/2014 12:09:24 PM" i checked in some time zone calcluator plus in oracle i should be getting "4/8/2014 04:09:24 PM" or "4/8/2014 16:09:24 PM" depending on hour format. why is it not converting into proper time format?

```
public static string ConvertDateTimeToUserTimeZone()
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("4/8/2014 11:09:24 AM");
    Instant now = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt,DateTimeKind.Utc));
    DateTimeZone dtZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
    ZonedDateTime zdt = now.InZone(dtZone);
    return zdt.ToDateTimeOffset().ToString("G");
}
```

Comment: Can you change the example code so that it doesn't rely on a value from an object we don't have, so that we can easily re-run your code? I mean, how can we verify that the problem is not that the value is in fact wrong, and you're just assuming it is correct?

Comment: Also, it would help that you pasted the code you're actually using. As it stands now, you're missing a quote after `"Europe/London` which makes me doubt that this is the real code.

Comment: FWIW, running the code through [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) gives me `04.08.2014 12:09:24` in the string.

Comment: What is your current culture of the code in the question after the edit? Meaning, how can you be sure the date is interpreted as the 4th of August or as the 8th of April?

Comment: Yea i actually i edited before pasting it here missed the ending quote here is the edited code for your reference

Comment: Well, you still haven't answered the comment that was deleted. Why should Europe/London be +5 hours, and not +1 as it correctly is?

Comment: its en-US and its in format mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: i checked in oracle way of time conversion as well as some time zone conversion/calculator sites

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: you can't have a parameter `now` *and* a local `now`. Can you post something that fully and accurately demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Can you link to one of those sites, because they are wrong, or you input the wrong values or misunderstood the values. Europe/London will never be +5 hours from UTC. At most it can be +2.

Comment: http://www.thetimezoneconverter.com/

Comment: http://www.happyzebra.com/timezones-worldclock/difference-between-London-and-New%20York.php

Comment: The problem here is that you're using an UTC time to do the conversion. London is UTC+1 right now, not +5 (and never will be). However, compared to New York there may be 5 hours difference, but *that's different!*

Comment: You should make sure your original instant comes from EDT, and then convert that to Europe/London. Since you're explicitly creating your instant from an UTC value, EDT never comes into the picture.

Comment: If your original values are not based on UTC, then you should start with `LocalDateTime`, and then apply the source time zone.  Noda will never assume you want the time zone of your machine.

Comment: Is it possible to show how to do that here i have been trying various approaches but not getting the solution

Comment: I am just wondering if a date time is stored in oracle do i need to convert it into UTC and then to EDT let say if the time is 5:30 pm converting it to UTC and the EDT will give UTC -04 offest will give 1:30 pm is it right since the original time is reduce to 4 hours hows this concept works

Answer (score 3):

Reading through your comments, it would appear that you'd like to do the following:

- Parse the input string
- Assign it to the the US Eastern time zone (`"America/New_York"`)
- Convert it to the time zone for the UK (`"Europe/London"`)
- Format it as a string in the general format

I will show using Noda Time for all of these steps, rather than mixing in non-Noda mechanisms.

```
var generalPattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithCurrentCulture("G");

string inputString = "4/8/2014 11:09:24 AM";
string sourceTimeZone = "America/New_York";
string targetTimeZone = "Europe/London";

LocalDateTime ldt1 = generalPattern.Parse(inputString).Value;
DateTimeZone tz1 = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[sourceTimeZone];
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ldt1.InZoneLeniently(tz1);

DateTimeZone tz2 = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[targetTimeZone];
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = zdt1.WithZone(tz2);
LocalDateTime ldt2 = zdt2.LocalDateTime;

string output = generalPattern.Format(ldt2);
```

Notice that I used `CreateWithCurrentCulture` when setting up the pattern.  This assumes you mean to use whatever the current culture is for the machine the code is running on.  If that's not the case, then you should set a specific culture instead.  This is important when you realize that users in the US will use M/D/Y formatting, while users in the UK will use D/M/Y formatting.  This applies to both dates regardless of time zone. (In other words, `4/8/2014` could be April 8th, or August 4th).

Also notice that I used `InZoneLeniently` when applying the source time zone.  This has lenient behavior when it comes to ambiguous and invalid input values due to [DST transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info). If you want different behavior, then you might instead use `InZoneStrictly`, or use `InZone` and provide your own algorithm.

And finally, it should be noted that I inferred from your comments that you were sourcing these from the US Eastern time zone, which would be either EDT or EST depending on what time of year it is.  If you actually meant that the values were *always* EDT, even when EST is the norm, then you would do the following:

```
DateTimeZone tz1 = DateTimeZone.ForOffset(Offset.FromHours(-4));
```

Answer (score 2):

The value you got back from the method is in fact correct.

Let's break it down using [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
void Main()
{
    var t = new DateTime(2014, 8, 4, 11, 09, 24, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var i = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(t);
    var s = ConvertDateTimeToUserTimeZone(i);
    s.Dump("User time zone value");
}

public static string ConvertDateTimeToUserTimeZone(Instant now)
{
    DateTimeZone dtZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
    dtZone.GetUtcOffset(now).Dump("TZ at instant");
    ZonedDateTime zdt = now.InZone(dtZone);
    return zdt.ToDateTimeOffset().ToString("G");
}
```

Output:

```
TZ at instant 
+01 

User time zone value 
04.08.2014 12:09:24
```

The time zone at the point of that instant is thus UTC+1, which means that the value you gave the code gives you the correct value back, 12:09.

To get 16:09, you would need UTC+5, and Europe/London has never been that value.

So 12:09:24 is correct, your assumptions that it should be 16:09:24 is wrong.

You need to go back to the code and/or sites you used to get the "correct" value, the source of your confusion is there, not in this code.

Comment: oh could be i ran the tz conversion code in oracle it gave me the same UTC+5 time made me wonder if its giving me the correct output or not thanks anyways

Comment: My current time zone is EDT eastern daylight time and i am looking into sites they say london is +5 hours ahead of EDT

Comment: Yes, but you're not doing time in relation to EDT, you're doing it in relation to UTC.

Comment: is there a way to get the EDT time and convert to a specific zone ?